# How to identify what kind of webserver im using

Tags: curl, http-headers, webserver

i need help to determine the type of webserver being used for remote content delivery.  I have tried to run curl -i. When i run `curl -i www.mywebsite.com` in the header information it says that

```
Server:server
```

It is not showing IIS or gws or apache etc.  I have access to the github for the server and i see a index.html file in there. Does that mean its apache ?

Comment: You may have to provide a real url so we can help you further.

Comment: What OS is it? If Linux, which distribution? Debian, Redhat, Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

> in the header information it says that `Server:server`

Sounds like this information has been purposely obscured.

Assuming that you are on a linux server with root permission, you can do the following:

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep "\(:80\|:443\)"
```

This will tell you the name of the server listening on port `80` or `443`. You will see something like `nginx`, `apache`, `httpd` etc.

Comment: do i need to be on the server itself to run this ? I only have the github of the server files. Im not on the server itself.  Can i run this command on my local machine ?

Comment: My mistake, I thought your question said you have access to the git repo from within the server. No `index.html` does not indicate it is Apache. Is there a `.htaccess` file by any chance?

Comment: nope theres no .htaaccess file i can see. There is some gradle build files present at the top level. I looked at the gradle build file. Its making a war file of this content.  Since its making a war file can i assume its tomcat ?

Comment: So it's a Java project. It could be using something like GlassFish or some other application server (there are many). To further complicate things, there could be a proxy server in front (`nginx` for example) which would also rewrite the server type from an external point of view. Looks like your best bet is to ask.